# iOS, Activity Monitor, need little insight

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, memory-leaks

I am trying to remove memory leaks using Instruments. Here is what I see.

[image]

When I click on that getHttpPOSTResultForVariables method highlighted in red, I see this

[image]

Can you please tell me, what exactly the second snapshot means.

Comment: Does getHttpPOSTResultForVariables returns an autoreleased objects?

Comment: @Cyprian - getHttpPOSTResultForVariables is coming from a static library, I don't know its implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mov r3, r5 means it moves an object from register 3 to register 5.

The red line means this is where the leak happens.

Which probably means that while moving the object from one register to the other the object in register 3 isn't cleaned up properly and thus gives a leak since you have now 2 registers with the same object without a direct reference to it.

What does this mean for your code? I'm not sure but I would look into the function that you use there.

Hope this help. Good luck